# In SQL Server, how to allow for multiple execution plans for a single query in a SP without having to recompile every time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

In SQL Server, what is the best way to allow for multiple execution plans to exist for a query in a SP without having to recompile every time?

For example, I have a case where the query plan varies significantly depending on how many rows are in a temp table that the query uses.  Since there was no "one size fits all" plan that was satisfactory, and since it was unacceptable to recompile every time, I ended up copy/pasting (ick) the main query in the SP multiple times within several IF statements, forcing the SQL engine to give each case its own optimal plan.  It actually seemed to work beautifully performance-wise, but it feels a bit clunky.  (I know I could similarly break this part out into multiple SPs to do the same thing.)  Is there a better way to do this?

```
IF @RowCount < 1
    [paste query here]
ELSE IF @RowCount < 50
    [paste query here]
ELSE IF @RowCount < 200
    [paste query here]
ELSE
    [paste query here]
```

Comment: One query/stored proc = one execution plan at any given time. There's no way I'm aware of to have multiple execution plans - depending on parameters. If you have some T-SQL code that varies vastly in terms of execution plans from one set of parameters to another, you might need to create multiple instances of that stored proc under separate names

Comment: @marc_s_ that's incorrect, kind of. SQL Server 2005+ has statement level recompilation and is better at dealing with this kind of branching. You have one plan still but the plan can be partially recompiled at the statement level.

Comment: I'm curious why 'with recompile' was unacceptable.  I do understand that compilation is not negligible in a query that would normally execute in microseconds.  But for a query that takes a few hundred milliseconds, it's often worth it over having to duplicate large queries.  option recompile does a lot of cool things like parameter folding where whole sections of the plan are eliminated.  It's not quite what you are looking for in terms of caching multiple distinct plans, but i do use it a lot for large queries that don't tend to be run in loops.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OPTIMIZE FOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) in certain situations, to create a plan targeted to a certain value of a parameter (but not multiple plans per se). This allows you to specify what parameter value we want SQL Server to use when creating the execution plan.  This is a SQL Server 2005 onwards hint.

[Optimize Parameter Driven Queries with the OPTIMIZE FOR Hint in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1354)

There is also [OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature.aspx) – a SQL Server 2008 onwards feature (use judiciously):

> This hint directs the query optimizer
>   to use the standard algorithms it has
>   always used if no parameters values
>   had been passed to the query at all.
>   In this case the optimizer will look
>   at all available statistical data to
>   reach a determination of what the
>   values of the local variables used to
>   generate the queryplan should be,
>   instead of looking at the specific
>   parameter values that were passed to
>   the query by the application.

Perhaps also look into [optimize for ad hoc workloads Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645587.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Mitch.  I had looked at these, but since there was no "one size fits all" plan they weren't as good as the "if block" approach I ended up using above.

Comment: @John: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027266/temp-table-and-stored-proc-compilation You lose nothing by Mitch's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005+ has statement level recompilation and is better at dealing with this kind of branching. You have one plan still but the plan can be partially recompiled at the statement level.

But it is ugly.

I'd go with @Mitch Wheat's option personally because you have recompilations anyway with the stored procedure using a temp table. See [Temp table and stored proc compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8027266/27535)

Comment: But those are table variables. They won't lead to recompiles unlike temp tables.