# Temp table and stored proc compilation

Tags: sql-server

Beginner question

but I believe there is lot of confusion still exists as this behavior changed between SQL Server versions between SQL 2000 and SQL 2005/later.

SQL Server 2000
Having a temp table in stored proc definition forces it to recompile it every time. So no execution plan is stored resulting in poor performance.

SQL 2005 and later
Even if you have temp table in your proc definition it won't recompile everytime it is executed. Execution plan will be resued.

Comment: What is your question exactly? [In any event you might want to read this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7477/optimization-moving-variable-declaration-to-top-of-procedure/7478#7478)

Comment: Simply put does having temp table in stored proc forces it to recompile everytime it runs?

Comment: My bad I just tested this on my SQL 2008 R2 Express
 
temp table in sP would not cause recompile and plan will be resued. 

Do not have SQL 2000 so Can't test but anyone still have SQL2000 around can confirm this

Answer (score 3):

You are entirely correct about SQL 2000. For SQL 2005, the statements that use the temp table are compiled seperately from the stored procedure and cached so that they can be reused.

See [Temporary Tables, Table Variables and Recompiles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2007/01/18/11-0-temporary-tables-table-variables-and-recompiles.aspx) on the SQL Programmability & API Development Team Blog. Scroll to the part that starts with "When the stored procedure DemoProc1 is compiled, the insert and select query are not compiled".

Comment: I advise anyone reading this answer to read the linked blog post, as it explains rather clearly when the plans are cached, and when they are not. You shouldn't assume the plan is usually reused.

Comment: Original link no longer exists.  Here is a cached copy from the wayback machine (https://web.archive.org/web/20120218072142/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2007/01/18/11-0-temporary-tables-table-variables-and-recompiles.aspx)